# Web.config for simple WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I have created the simple web service.
Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITsdxService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    string Test();
}

public class TsdxService : ITsdxService
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }

    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Test.TSDX.UI.TsdxService">
    <endpoint 
        address="Tsdx"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="TestBinding"
        contract="Test.TSDX.UI.ITsdxService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TestBinding" />
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I run from Visual Studio I put localhost:50517/TsdxService.svc?wsdl all works fine - I can see wsdl, but when I put localhost:50517/TsdxService.svc/Tsdx/Test or localhost:50517/TsdxService.svc/Tsdx/DoWork I don't see anything. The Fiddler tells me that I got 400 error. Breakpoints (on Test and DoWork methods) don't work. Why? What did I do incorrect?

Comment: Try changing your binding to basicHTTP.

Comment: @lain Have changed - all the same. 400 error code.

Comment: Can you double check you have the WCF Features switched on within Win7, goto Add/Remove programs, Add Feature, Click under the Microsoft.net Framework 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the *[WebGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx)* attribute to your service operations.

```
[WebGet]
public string Test() 
{
    ...
}
```

For this to work, you also need to add [WebScriptEnablingBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpbehavior.aspx) to the service configuration.  Also, use the *webHttpBinding*.  These things are all required to allow the service to work as an AJAX service.

*Definition:*

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

*Reference:*

```
<endpoint behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior"
    binding="webHttpBinding"
    ...
/>
```